# image threasholding in opencv (thereshold to 255)

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this code which is work well:

```
cv::threshold( image, out, 20, 255,cv::THRESH_TOZERO );
```

In this code, all pixels which are less than 20, became zero. Now I want to write a code that all pixels which are more than say 230, became 255.

Is there any way to do this?

I know that I can iterate over all pixels, but I am looking for a simpler solutions.

Comment: what's wrong with `threshold( image, out, 230, 255, THRESH_BINARY)`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no parameter for CV::threshold that does this, but you could simply use THRESH_BINARY and then [get the maximum](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#max) of your original image and the thresholded image.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no parameter for threshold to do this (based on this document http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html)! Why should I get the max of original image?

Comment: you should get the *per-element maximum* of the *combination* of your original image *and* the thresholded image (with THRESH_BINARY), because that will result in the image that you want. Just call the max function from the link with both the original and the thresholded image as parameters, and observe the output.